# Openshift/Kubernetes liveliness probe Spring actuator

Tags: spring, kubernetes, openshift, spring-boot-actuator

I have implemented spring actuator health endpoints and added this in the Livelines probe - 
http-get http://:8080/actuator/health

when i describe the pod I don't see the #success counter is increasing

http-get http://:8080/actuator/health delay=60s timeout=20s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3

How to know if the liveliness probe is actually running with the default actuator's health endpoint

Answer (score 1):

The value of success here is **successThreshold**.  It is **not a counter field**

`kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.livenessProbe.successThreshold`

```
DESCRIPTION:
     Minimum consecutive successes for the probe to be considered successful
     after having failed. Defaults to 1. Must be 1 for liveness. Minimum value
     is 1.
```

similarly there is a failure threshold

`kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.livenessProbe.failureThreshold`

> When a Pod starts and the probe fails, Kubernetes will try failureThreshold times before giving up. Giving up in case of liveness probe means restarting the container. In case of readiness probe the Pod will be marked Unready. Defaults to 3. Minimum value is 1.[configure-probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes)

---

> How to know if the liveliness probe is actually running with the default actuator's health endpoint

check the logs of your pod

`kubectl logs -f $pod`

or check the log of kubelet, which is probing the pod

`journalctl -f -u kubelet`